# animate on click works only once

Tags: jquery

I want the `ul` to move to the left by 200 each time, but it only happens once. Why?

```
$('a.next').click(function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        $('ul#pikame').animate({
            'left': -200
        });
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try:

```
'left': '-=200'
```

You're only setting the value statically.

Basically you're saying "set left value to -200". What you want to say is: "decrease left value by 200"

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the `'left': -200` to `'left': '-=200'`

Answer (score 1):

It's because -200 implies move to -200px not -200 more pixels try this.

```
$('a.next').click(function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        $('ul#pikame').animate({
            'left': $('ul#pikame').position().left-200
        });
        e.preventDefault();
});
```